# Skipping specific indices in an array (or addressing intervals of indices)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that I want to address specific indices of it by ignoring a few in the middle. Probably this is the worst way of doing it:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(15)
b=np.append(np.append(a[0:6],a[9:10]),a[13:15])
print b
```

Is there a smart way of addressing intervals of indices for an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boolean indexing?

```
In [30]:

a[(np.indices(a.shape)!=7).flatten()]
Out[30]:
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9])

In [35]:

a[~np.in1d(np.indices(a.shape), (7,9))]
Out[35]:
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8])
```

Comment: Thanks but I changed my example a bit. I think your method handles what I want.

Comment: Yeah, use that `in1d` version, change the 2nd argument to `(7,8,11,12)`, :P.